# How to merge one single revision using Command Line

Tags: svn

Hi I am trying to merge one single revision using CL in SVN using this command:

```
svn merge -r 5454 URL
```

but I am getting the following error

```
svn: Second revision required
```

My revision is not the latest revision but buried about 90 revisions from the latest update. Any thoughts on what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

When you need to provide a diff (including `diff` and `merge` commands), you can use either `-rSTART:FINISH` (`-r5453:5454` in your case) or `-cSINGLE` (`-c5454` in your case).

Answer (score 6):

```
svn --accept theirs-full merge -c 25757 <URL_OF_THE_FILE>
```

Where the `25757` is a revision number